# Compile client-side Jade templates using Gulpjs

Tags: javascript, templates, pug, gulp

I'm trying to compile all my .jade templates into a single js file, I'm using Gulpjs and gulp-jade, gulp-concat..

I can get the single file but the problem is that all the functions rendered there have the same name, they are all called "template".

foo.jade:

```
.fooDiv
    h1 Foo here
```

foo2.jade:

```
.foo2Div
    h1 Foo2 here
```

Gulp file:

```
gulp.src("templates/**/*.jade")
    .pipe(jade({client: true}))
    .pipe(concat("templates.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("../website/templates"))
```

That would output a file like this:

```
function template(locals) {
    var buf = [];
    var jade_mixins = {};

    buf.push("<div class=\"fooDiv\"><h1>Foo here</h1></div>");;return buf.join("");
}
function template(locals) {
    var buf = [];
    var jade_mixins = {};

    buf.push("<div class=\"foo2Div\"><h1>Foo2 here</h1></div>");;return buf.join("");
}
```

And what I want is something like:

```
function foo(locals) {
    var buf = [];
    var jade_mixins = {};

    buf.push("<div class=\"fooDiv\"><h1>Foo here</h1></div>");;return buf.join("");
}
function foo2(locals) {
    var buf = [];
    var jade_mixins = {};

    buf.push("<div class=\"foo2Div\"><h1>Foo2 here</h1></div>");;return buf.join("");
}
```

Is there any way I can do this? I've been searching for quite some time now and didn't find anything.

Cheers.
Caio

Edit:

Jade now accepts the name option for jade.compileClient. Check it here: https://github.com/jadejs/jade/blob/master/jade.js

Comment: Would be useful to add the edit as an answer and mention how/if you changed the `name` value dynamically.

Comment: @SebastianThomas I found [this comment](https://github.com/mariusGundersen/gulp-forEach/issues/6#issuecomment-82454274) helpful.  I've posted this solution as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that `jade.compileClient` hard-codes `function template(locals)` and it has no option to change the function name. https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/lib/jade.js

This is a bit hacky but you can modify the contents of the compiled scripts after the jade compilation.

```
var through = require('through2');
var path = require('path');

function modify() {
  function transform(file, enc, callback) {
    if (!file.isBuffer()) {
      this.push(file);
      callback();
      return;
    }
    var funcName = path.basename(file.path, '.js');
    var from = 'function template(locals) {';
    var to = 'function ' + funcName + '(locals) {';
    var contents = file.contents.toString().replace(from, to);
    file.contents = new Buffer(contents);
    this.push(file);
    callback();
  }
  return through.obj(transform);
}

gulp.src("templates/**/*.jade")
    .pipe(jade({client: true}))
    .pipe(modify())
    .pipe(concat("templates.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("../website/templates"));
```

You can change the `funcName` as you like based on `file.path` if your jade templates are in multiple subdirectories.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: @aditya_m If you use pugjs, you should use `name` option instead of this hacky solution. https://pugjs.org/api/reference.html

Comment: Thanks @ShuheiKagawa, any pointers on how to use this for client side templating? I'm using gulp and gulp-pug to pre-compile the templates as js functions, and then call them from client side code (passing JSON from AJAX as locals) to render the page.

Comment: gulp-pug's options are passed into pug. So probably you can just add `name` option to gulp-pug.

Comment: Ah, but then it cannot set `name` for each file. Now I understand what you mean...

Answer (score 3):

The following code snippet comes from [this comment](https://github.com/mariusGundersen/gulp-forEach/issues/6#issuecomment-82454274) that I found to be very helpful.

```js
gulp.task('strings', function() {
    return gulp.src('media/templates/*.jade')
        .pipe(foreach(function(stream,file){
            var filename = path.basename(file.path);
            filename = filename.split('.')[0]
            return stream
                .pipe(jade({
                    client: true,
                    name: filename
                }));
        }))
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('media/strings/'))
});
```

Using [gulp-foreach](https://github.com/mariusGundersen/gulp-forEach) you can get the current file's name, change it, and then pass it on to jade.  After that you can perform other actions, like `concat`, as normal.

Answer (score 2):

I found an elegant solution that works for me.

Basically, in your main script (the one you load BEFORE the jade generated scripts in your .html file), you have an array that will hold the returned values of the template() functions, say `var document = [];`

You then use `gulp-insert` to wrap to the scripts `'(function() {'` and `;\n;document.push(template()); })();`, then concatenate those scripts as you have already done.

Now pop the `document[]` array as you need, with the computed values from each `template()` call inside!

I use LiveScript for my build, but here is a converted JavaScript version:

```
var jade   = require('gulp-jade');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var insert = require('gulp-insert');
gulp.task('jade-to-js', function(){
  return gulp.src('src/node/jade/*.jade')
  .pipe(jade({client: true}))
  .pipe(insert.wrap('(function() {', '\n;document.push(template()); })();')
  .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('src/js/'))
});
```

Comment: Is there a way of declaring the array at the start of bundle.js.

Comment: @Ian Warburton - what I do is to simply include a script with the document array BEFORE including bundle.js - it works :)